# Include MetadataURL (Metadata Link) in layer coverage programmatically

Tags: geoserver, java

I'm using GeoServer's Java API library, and am trying to add add the MetadataURL to a coverage layer programmatically.  I can add it from within GeoServer's layer setup admin page.  I just don't see anywhere in the API where I can set it.

For example, this is what I see in the layer when I have the Metadata Link set.  How would I add this in using the Java API?

How the actual URL is made and it's content is trivial.

`<MetadataURL type="ISO19115:2003">
        <Format>text/plain</Format>
        <OnlineResource 
         xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/gogc/wcs?
         request=DescribeCoverage&version=2.0.1&service=WCS&CoverageId=HYCOM-
         GLOBAL:Region06.salinityWater.DBSL"/>
    </MetadataURL>`

Comment: assuming you mean the REST API the usual process is to add one manually (in the GUI) and then do a GET request to see what you should sent

Comment: Thanks iant for the response.  I'm referring to the Java API.  I was able to find a class that looks like it might handle it...[Geoserver Github](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/55c4740060eb2b8809ae935a510ac83eeb923313/src/main/src/main/java/org/geoserver/catalog/impl/MetadataLinkInfoImpl.java)